# maven command line - plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven, configuration, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm in the need to run integration tests one by one with the failsafe plugin *(please, don't ask why... They just have to run in individual jvms, one good reason for avoiding singletons)*.

So I'd like to create a script with one maven call per line where each maven call runs tests on a single test file. Something like this:

```
mvn failsafe:integration-test -D<???>=**/ITest1.java
mvn failsafe:integration-test -D<???>=**/ITest2.java
mvn failsafe:integration-test -D<???>=**/ITest3.java
...
```

In a pom.xml I'd add something like

```
<includes>
  <include>**/ITest1.java</include>
</includes>
```

to the plugins configuration. Is there a way to achieve the same with the command line? Is it possible to specify list-like configuration options?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is:

```
mvn -Dit.test=TestName verify
```

Source: [Failsafe Plugin Examples: Running a Single Test](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html)

Answer (score 2):

The `it.test` parameter does that. You can read about it [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test).

From the docs:

> [...] so you can just type "-Dit.test=MyTest" to run a single test called "foo/MyTest.java".